# Binding nested knockout model to checkbox fails

Tags: knockout.js

I am not able to bind this:

js:

```
function User(jsonModel) {

    self.show= ko.observable(jsonModel.show);

}

function ViewModel(jsonModel) {
    var self = this;
    self.user = ko.observable(new User(jsonModel.User));

}
```

to this:

```
    <input id="it" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: user.show" />
```

the checkbox is unticked regardless. 
I have also checked that viewModel .user() = true here:

```
        var viewModel = new ViewModel(json);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unwrap `user` observable:

```
<input id="it" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: user().show" />
```

Comment: ah cool, how come I see it in other situations where you don't need to unwrap it?

Comment: You need to unwrap it only in expressions.